# pass html to polymer element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

from the polymer documents (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties) I found how to pass arguments to elements like this:

```
<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'x-custom',

    properties: {
      userName: String
    }

  });

</script>

<x-custom user-name="Scott"></x-custom>
```

But is it possible to pass html as well?
e.g.

```
<my-element>
     <h1>Hello world<h2>
</my-element>
```

I've created a 'my-element' in polymer and would like to add content to it. The polymer element sole purpose is to style all content inside (the h1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `<content>` element which is built into Polymer. This allows you to create an insertion point for some child content. For example declaring an element using the `<content>` element:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      ::content h1 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <content></content>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and then using this element:

```
<my-element>
  <h1>This heading is red</h1>
</my-element>
```

Here is more information on the [content](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution) tag as well as [styling](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#styling-distributed-children-content) the content.

Comment: ty! is this also allowed in polymer 2?

Comment: Yes although in Polymer 2.0, the `<content>` element has been replaced with the `<slot>` element. There is more information on the [upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#dom-template)

Comment: indeed, found it here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade